# Display a programmable field several times on the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am a newbie. Can anyone help me?

I have made a function with a programmable input field. I want to call this function several times and display the results at different coordinates on the screen.

What do I wrong and how should I solve it?

```
// inputName function

NSString* inputName (
       int controlX,
       int ControlY,
       int controlWidth,
       int controlHeight,
       NSString* myQuestion)
{

  // *********************** Inputfield **********************
  UITextField *inlogName=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(controlX,controlY,controlWidth, controlHeight)];

  [inlogName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
  [inlogName setPlaceholder: myQuestion];

  [inlogName setDelegate:self]; // HERE I GET AN ERROR ???????

  [inlogName text];
  NSString *anwser= @"This is a dummy anwser"; 

  [self.view addSubview:inlogName];  // HERE I GET ALSO AN ERROR ??????

  return anwser;
}
```

Comment: What is the subclass of the class you run this code?

Comment: First of all there is a typing error on the addSubview line, you wrote inLogNaam instead of inlogName. And the method variables are also not camelCase. You receive int ControlX for example and create the rect using controlX. Fix that and run again...

Answer (score 1):

You have created a C function and have no reference to self in it.  I would suggest making it a method on your view controller and invoke it from there.